# XNA - Extract rotation vector (angles) from world matrix

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I got the positoin, forward and up vectors of an object. I'm using

```
Matrix.CreateWorld(Position, Forward, Up);
```

To get the world matrix, but I don't know how to extract the rotation vector.
Also there is another way to get rotation vector out of position, forward and up vectors?

tnx.

Comment: Check out http://www.gamedev.net/topic/547357-extracting-euler-rotation-from-direction/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the decompose method:

```
 world.Decompose(out traslation, out rotation , out scale);
```